# Central line number for large function with algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e, line-numbering

I have an algorithm (using algorithm2e) where I need a big function, so I want to enter it as an equation. But the line numbering seems a bit weird, as it numbers an empty line. I want the number to be central (technically on the level of the fraction bar).

I have

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e} % nice and easy (?) pseudocode

\begin{document} 

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{A cool algorithm}
        \ForEach {item $\in$ set}{
                \[
                    \frac
                    {numerator}
                    {denominator}
                \]
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

but this results in:

[image: A non-working example]

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373693/center-line-number-for-equation-in-algorithm) as a similar question, but it did not work properly. (It added a wrong number at the correct spot).
Numbering works properly for single-line equations, but then the fraction is too small to read.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Uhm, `algorithm2e` has an environment `algomathdisplay` for this but it seems to be faulty. But if the problem of the inline math fraction is only the size, would a simple `\ForEach{item $\in$ set}{$\displaystyle\frac{numerator}{denominator}$}` be enough?

Comment: I have to be honest, I did not know of algomathdisplay. Tried it, as you said it is faulty. I did not think on displaystyle. That might do, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose here two solutions: one uses simply inline math preceded by `\displaystyle`; the other uses a newly defined environment which just adds some space around the math expression (also typeset in `\displaystyle`)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\newenvironment{varalgomathdisplay}%
   {\qquad$\vcenter\bgroup\kern2ex\hbox\bgroup$\displaystyle}%
   {$\egroup\kern1ex\egroup$}

\begin{document} 

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{A cool algorithm}
        \ForEach {item $\in$ set}{$\displaystyle\frac{num}{den}$}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Another cool algorithm}
        \ForEach {item $\in$ set}{\begin{varalgomathdisplay}\frac{num}{den}\end{varalgomathdisplay}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]